# C++ Vertex Buffer Issue

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I'm attempting to add a vertex buffer to the Mesh.cpp file of the [pixel city](https://code.google.com/p/pixelcity/) procedural city-generating program.  Part of the current code looks like this:

```
for (qsi = _quad_strip.begin(); qsi < _quad_strip.end(); ++qsi) {
  glBegin (GL_QUAD_STRIP);
  for (n = qsi->index_list.begin(); n < qsi->index_list.end(); ++n) {
    glTexCoord2fv (&_vertex[*n].uv.x);
    glVertex3fv (&_vertex[*n].position.x);
  }
    glEnd ();
}
```

This draws textures onto the rectangular sides of some of the buildings.  Just going off the VBO tutorials I've found online, I attempt to convert this to use a vertex buffer like so (I store vboId in Mesh.h):

```
for (qsi = _quad_strip.begin(); qsi < _quad_strip.end(); ++qsi) {
    void * varray = (char *) malloc(sizeof(GLfloat)*5*qsi->index_list.size());
    GLfloat *p = (GLfloat*)varray;

    int counter = 0;
    for (n = qsi->index_list.begin(); n < qsi->index_list.end(); ++n) {
      memcpy(&p[counter+0],&_vertex[*n].uv.x, sizeof(GLfloat)*2);
      memcpy(&p[counter+2],&_vertex[*n].position.x, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);
      counter+=5;
    }
    glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboId);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(GLfloat)*5*qsi->index_list.size(), p, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat)*5, (GLfloat*)0); 
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat)*5,  (GLfloat*)2);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 0, qsi->index_list.size());

    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    free(varray);
   }
```

However, this code simply doesn't work.  Nothing is rendered.  Sometimes, when I mess with the parameters into glTexCoordPointer or glVertexPointer, I really skewed/garbage data drawn on the screen (or the program crashes), but nothing that has even come close to remotely working.

Comment: Using a new buffer for every loop iteration kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: Also, this is going to fail after a few frames, since you're leaking VBO memory rapidly.

Comment: I was planning on just getting this to work first, and then moving it outside the loop later.

Comment: Thing is, your data is already laid out exactly like it needs to be for a single VBO.  You can just slurp the entire `_vertex` array.  And then use pass the `n` list of indexes to `glDrawArrays`.  In fact, right now it looks like you're rearranging the vertex data to be contiguous and then passing an discontiguous set of indices -- that won't turn out well.

Comment: oops, sorry.  It is `glDrawElements` that you'll pass the indexes to.  `glDrawArrays` does expect the data in sequential order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vertex pointer is wrong. When using VBOs, the pointer is interpreted as the byte offset relative to the currently bound buffer. So, you need sizeof(GLfloat)*2 bytes as offset.

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat)*5,  (char*)0 +sizeof(GLfloat)*2);
```

As a side note: you could save the additional data copy if you would create the VBO with the correct size but `NULL` as the data pointer (which basically creates the data storage) and memory-map it with `glMapBuffer()`, completely avoivding the `malloc()`ed temporary buffer you use.

Comment: Thank-you so much!  That fixed it!  Definitely wish I had posted about this earlier, would have saved me a ton of trouble:)  I'll also look into using glMapBuffer().

Comment: How about `2 + (GLfloat*)0` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: well, if you like that better. Why not `2[(GLfloat*)0]`?

Comment: 2 + (GLfloat*)0 also works interestingly.  I guess there are a lot of things I failed to try.  2[(GLfloat*)0] doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @Brutalisk: Yeah, my bad. It actually would try to derefence that pointer. &2[(GLfloat*)0] should compile, but I would not recommend using such crap.